# How to get Xorg to use the wacom driver for my graphics tablet?

Tags: xorg, input, tablet

I just got a Wacom graphics tablet, plugged it in, installed the drivers and it mostly works. However `xsetwacom` and the KDE tablet settings module don't recognize it. Upon inspection of `Xorg.0.log` I have discovered that Xorg uses the `evdev` driver instead of the proper `wacom` one. What do I have to do in order to use the correct driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recognize that Wacom tablets are best used with the `wacom` driver, Xorg needs an `Xorg.xonf` entry. Luckily you don't have to add one manually but it comes with the driver. On Gentoo, the config snippet is located in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf`. If you didn't have the wacom driver installed the last time the X server was started, Xorg won't have read it. Thus, to get it to fully recognize your tablet, just restart the X server.